# What is fastest, @Entity or @Embedded?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Im new (today) to the NoSql MongoDb and trying to understand the Morphia.
I want to have one @Entity like this:

If i have 3 Tables (Collections) named
Stat
Friendlist
Userdata
I save UserData.Class in Userdata right and Statistic.Class in Stat and so on...

My thought was if i give each user a unique ObjectId UUID nr and then every Statistic and FriendList having this UUID nr as there ObjectId. Because if the program need to run statistic only, it will load/work against Statistic only.

```
@Entity
public class UserData {

    @Id private ObjectId id = "UUID 123456789;
    public String userName = "";
    public String password = "";    
    @Embedded
    private Statistic statistic;
    @Embedded
    private FriendList friendList;
}
```

If there are like 18000/hour request to get the UserData would it not be faster to declare them like this:
( i use the same ObjectId and they ares stored in separate Collections (tables)

```
@Entity
public class UserData {

    @Id private ObjectId id = "UUID 123456789;
    public String userName = "";
    public String password = "";
}

@Entity
public class Statistic {

    @Id private ObjectId id = "UUID 123456789;
    public int loginTimes;
    public String gps;

}

@Entity
public class FriendList {

    @Id private ObjectId id = "UUID 123456789;
    public ArrayList<String> fiends;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the correct is use DBRef or Embedded.

If you want some object of the list in other object too, use DBRef, if not, use embedded.

For example, in a blog post, the comments will never be used in another post, so, its embedded.

So, use somehting like:

```
@Entity
public class UserData {

@Id private ObjectId id = "UUID 123456789;
public String userName = "";
public String password = "";    
@Embedded
private Statistic statistic;
@Embedded
private List<Friends> friendList;
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: the Statistic and FriendList can be used outside, f.ex if i only want to collect statistic i will request all Statistic from the (Document)Table named "Stat" and use the ObjectId inside the Statistic to find out who this UserData belonge to. Is this not better then have to get all UserData because the Statistic is inside  UserData , maybe im thinking wrong...

Comment: hm.. if i understand you right, try to do like I say, but, use dbref annotation instead of embedded in friendlist... morphia automatically do what you trying to do manually, of course, if I understand you right.. my english is not that good :). Test it, and say what you got.

Comment: you can find info on morphia wiki :) code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Embedded is always faster because Reference stored in different physical location.